# How to declare a variable of type "Date?" not "DateTime?"

Tags: wpf

I have create patient form in which user might or might not enter date of birth of the patient.
The control I have used for it is Date Picker and binded it to the PatientDateOfBirth
but when i try to access PatientDateOfBirth.HasValue it gives me null.

Property

```
public DateTime? PatientDateOfBirth
    {
        get
        {
            if (_patientDateOfBirth.HasValue)
                return _patientDateOfBirth.Value;
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            _patientDateOfBirth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PatientDateOfBirth");
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dPPatDOB" Text="{Binding Path=Model.PatientDateOfBirth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="12,11,98,29"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no `Date` type you have to use `DateTime` and ignore the time

the `PatientDateOfBirth` property returns null because you are using `Text` Property

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dPPatDOB" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Model.PatientDateOfBirth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="12,11,98,29"/>
```

Note: use `SelectedDate` Property not `Text`